# jquery ui sortable refresh doesn't trigger update?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

```
update: function(event, ui) {
            console.dir("update");    
        },
```

Why update is not triggered by:

```
$(...).sortable('refresh');
```

?

And if it's not supposed to, than how to I trigger event after refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.trigger('update')` if you wish.

I would question why a refresh requires an `update`. Maybe better to have the functionality elsewhere and call it after the refresh.